# Passing Large XML data to xml datatype parameter in ADODB

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, asp-classic, ado

I have a procedure that takes a xml datatype parameter

```
create procedure my_procedure
    @xml_parameter xml
as
begin
(...)
end
```

And i call that procedure from a classic asp page, using a command like this:

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")        
cmd.ActiveConnection = MyConnObj
cmd.CommandText = "my_procedure"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@xml_parameter", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(xmlData), xmlData)
```

It's working if i pass a small xml. But when i pass a large xml, +- 200 Kb, I get the message "The procedure expects the @xml_parameter parameter, wich was not informed".

Does anyone know how i can pass this xml to the stored procedure?

PS: It also works when i call the procedure from "SQL Server Management Studio" with the same xml data, so it seems the limitation is from the ADO.

### Edit in 2014-jun-19:

Debugging the problem i discovered a message from ODBC Driver saying that some data are being truncated. I tried to change the driver, by using "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}", but now i get the message : "The metadata could not be determined because statement (...) uses a temp table"

Comment: Pass the length as `-1` not the actual length, SQL Server will interpret it as `varchar(max)`.

Comment: I tried that ,but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully submit over 7MB of data into procedure's parameter by using ADODB 2.8, Parameters.Refresh method to initially build the parameters, AppendChunk method to built its value and changing parameter's type to adLongVarWChar before execution (originally it was adVarWChar)

Answer (score 0):

.Refresh query the database for parameters, hence you get an extra DB communication.
all need to be done instead of refresh is pass the length as Len+1, for the null terminating character.